# Connecting to Oracle database from Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, oracle11g, cx-oracle

Trying to connect to Oracle database from Python using cx-oracle. I followed steps mentioned in this link:https://gist.github.com/thom-nic/6011715

I am running Python 2.7.8. on Yosemite(10.10.2).After I unzip instant client into this path on my machine: /Users/ayada/Library/Share/oracle which is set to ORACLE_HOME and have set both DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH to ORACLE_HOME. I use Pip(env ARCHFLAGS="-arch $ARCH" pip install cx_Oracle) to install cx_oracle but encountering following error:
distutils.errors.DistutilsSetupError:

Oracle home (/Users/ayada/Library/Share/oracle) does not refer to an 9i, 10g, 11g or 12c installation.

Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/22/78xh65wd3xq232p4zd18l8800013hw/T/pip_build_ayada/cx-Oracle
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/ayada/.pip/pip.log

To give some context, I don't have Oracle database installed on my machine but I am trying to connect to a remote server.

I am relatively newbie to working on Mac and doing these kind of setups. Please advice.

Comment: are you able to connect to oracle database using sqlplus?

Comment: yes, I generally work on SQL developer and connect to db. But here the problem seems to be not connecting to db but at installing cx_oracle. I will connect to db once I have cx_oracle downloaded. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you done as kevindalias advised in the comments section of the link you pasted?

> Seems like Oracle made a change to the basic zip since this was posted, so to anyone else who arrives here:

`ln -s libclntsh.dylib.11.2 libclntsh.dylib
ln -s libocci.dylib.11.2 libocci.dylib`

> should be...

`ln -s libclntsh.dylib.11.1 libclntsh.dylib
ln -s libocci.dylib.11.1 libocci.dylib`

> You'll see both 11.1 files when you unpack the zips, and the links need to point to them. With this tweak, I was able to install cx_Oracle 5.1.2 on OS X 10.8.5 using 64-bit versions of Oracle Instant Client 11.2 and Python 2.7.6. Good luck.

Also I don't know about Mac, but in RHEL, my ORACLE_HOME is different to LD_LIBRARY_PATH:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64`

Comment: @abhi : I have the same issue, were you able to resolve it ?